# Program addEventListener does not detect event being emitted

Tags: solana-program, rust

```
program.addEventListener("GameResult", (event, game, res) => {
    console.log("EVENT: ", event, game, res)
})
```

Sometimes it registers the event, sometimes it does not. I don't know what the hell is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised example with proper event emission and listener attachment:

```
// Define the event emitter function
function emitGameResultEvent() {
    // ... Your event emission code here ...
}

// Add the event listener
program.addEventListener("GameResult", (event, game, res) => {
    console.log("EVENT: ", event, game, res);
});

// Emit the event somewhere in your code
emitGameResultEvent();
```

Make sure that the event emission is happening consistently and that the listener is added before any events are emitted. If you're still facing issues, double-check the event name for any typos.